# Flex mobile: View with DateSpinner takes awfully long to get displayed

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex-mobile

```
<s:DateSpinner id="dateSpinner" displayMode="dateAndTime" />
```

A view containg above code, and displayed with **navigator.pushView()** takes quite a few seconds to be displayed, even if DateSpinner is the only thing on the view.

Is there a way to speed this up? It really is a horrible user experience.

I'm of course talking about the performance on device, iPhone4. It runs OK in the emulator.

**Update: full view code.**

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="DateView">

    <s:DateSpinner id="dateSpinner" displayMode="dateAndTime" />

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="back" click="{navigator.popView()}"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
</s:View>
```

Comment: That code doesn't really help.  Can you post the full view?  Do you have any code running in the initialize or preinitialize or creationComplete or updateComplete or viewActivated events?  Do you use a transition?  Is there anything else "floating" out there in memory?  What hardware are you testing on?  I've done some sample apps with DateSpinner that had three views (each w/ different configs of DateSpinner) and used default transitions between them and had no noticeable performance issues.

Comment: That's encouraging to hear. I posted now the full code, the device is iPhone4 as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't really be any other issues, unless the previous view is taking up some memory, or exercising some transitions, because that view you're using is about as basic as can be.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue on Android. Seems to be an issue with the component itself.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I used the same simple code from above and the view takes A LOT of time to be displayed.